# How to draw border all the way around bar element

Tags: chart.js

I would like to use chart.js to draw a bar in a horizontal bar chart that has a border all the way around.

As can be seen on the image I'm successful in applying a border but I can't figure out how to get a border on the left side; which would make it a full square.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [`borderSkipped`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/charts/bar.html#borderskipped) option to `false`, depending on if you do it in the options or on the dataset level it will apply to all bars or only the bars of that specific dataset.

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 5,
      borderColor: 'pink',
      borderSkipped: false //Apply setting only to this bar dataset
    }]
  },
  options: {
    elements: {
      bar: {
        borderSkipped: false // Apply setting to all bar datasets
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!